# jquery ui autocomplete undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    $("#restaurant_name_search").autocomplete({
        source: function(d, e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: api_url + 'searchrestuarant/' + encodeURIComponent(d.term),
                success: function(b) {
                    var c = [];
                    b = JSON.parse(b);
                    $.each(b, function(i) {
                        i.label = i.Restaurant_Name;
                        c.push(i);
                    });
                    e(c);
                }
            })
        },
        select: function(a, b) {
            console.log(b);.
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>") // <---
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

This is my jquery ui call.

The json output is as follows:

```
[{
    "Restaurant_Key": "1",
    "Restaurant_Name": "Altitude Espresso",
    "Email": "",
    "Phone_1": "",
    "Local_Restaurant_Key": "1",
    "Address_Line1": "163 Oriordian Street",
    "City": "Mascot"
}]
```

But always the autocomplete shows undefined.

The output is receieved from url.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is the index, so your code should be:

```
 var c = [];
 b = JSON.parse(b);
 $.each(b, function(index, item) {
   item.label = item.Restaurant_Name;
   c.push(item);
 });
```

But instead of manually creating the array and mutating the original object, you can better use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var c = $.map(b, function(item, index) {
   return {label : item.Restaurant_Name};
});
```

In this case the order of arguments is what you were expecting.